# convert CCRenderTexture to many CCSprites fast

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, ccsprite

I am working on my game using cocos2d + box2d for iphone.

I need freehand drawing on screen like [this](http://build-failed.blogspot.ru/2012/08/freehand-drawing-with-cocos2d-x-and.html).
But i don't need bodies to be dynamic, I need static bodies and the line I drawn have to fade out after a few seconds from starting to finishing points.

So,i decided to use the code from the article above for drawing on CCRenderTexture.
I am also add a new static b2body after every N points (and store array of points for each body in array). After a few seconds i use the second brush with blending function

```
{ GL_ZERO,GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA }
```

and visit all points of the body (like for the drawing) to erase part of my line.

It works fine, but a bit slowly when I draw a long line.
Besides that, this method erases all intersections of lines.

I tried another way - to create a CCSprite from CCRenderTexture every N points and clear CCRenderTexture for further drawing.
It looks more beauty, but more slowly on the other hand (I had near 10 fps when draw just two lines with two CCSprites).

I think the "bottleneck" of this it's the method of creating CCSprite:

```
CCTexture2D *tex = [[[CCTexture2D alloc] initWithCGImage:  
[self.target getUIImage].CGImage resolutionType:kCCResolutionUnknown] autorelease];
CCSprite *wallSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:tex];
[self addChild:wallSprite];
wallSprite.position = ccp(s.width/2, s.height/2);
[self.target clear:0 g:0 b:0 a:0];
```

Is there any another way to create CCSprite from CCRenderTexture which WILL NOT MODIFY when I clear CCRenderTexture after and will work faster.
Or maybe there are better solutions for my problem?

Thanks!

Comment: OK, now i pointed out that creating the texture isn't so slow, but when i add ccsprite, created from this texture to my scene, fps is going down from 30 to 20 and lower for each additional sprite.
How can it be optimized?